# JQuery Datatables set a different column value when a checkbox is selected in same row

Tags: datatables

I am using latest .Net core and Datatables in my app.  I have the triggers set in the javascript for a adding a checkbox to column 1 (0) of the table and I also have a "select all" functioning on the column header and the intermediate status showing on the header.  That all works great.

The data is for a list of pharmacies, the amount billed and the actual amount paid.  I would like to click the checkbox for the pharmacy and then automatically fill in the amount paid cell with the full amount of the amount billed cell.  Conversely, blank out the paid amount if pharmacy is unchecked.

| cb | Pharmacy | Billed | Paid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | pharm1 | 100 | 100 |
|  | pharm2 | 200 | 0 |
|  | pharm3 | 300 | 0 |
| X | pharm4 | 400 | 400 |

Code for the checkboxes was straight from datatables site and is below :

```
    // Handle click on "Select all" control
    $('#pharmacyTable-select-all').on('click', function () {
            // Check/uncheck all checkboxes in the table
            var rows = pharmacyTable.rows({ 'search': 'applied' }).nodes();
            $('input[type="checkbox"]', rows).prop('checked', this.checked);
        });

    // Handle click on checkbox to set state of "Select all" control
    $('#pharmacyTable tbody').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function () {
            // If checkbox is not checked
            if (!this.checked) {
                var el = $('#pharmacyTable-select-all').get(0);
                // If "Select all" control is checked and has 'indeterminate' property
                if (el && el.checked && ('indeterminate' in el)) {
                    // Set visual state of "Select all" control
                    // as 'indeterminate'
                    el.indeterminate = true;
                }
            }
        });
```

What needs to change for this functionality?

Comment: Where is your attempt to do what you've described?  We don't need to see the code that works.  We need to see the code you're having a problem with, and then explain at what point in that code segment you aren't getting the result you expect.

Comment: The question is where to start?  The first code block is specific to the header of the checkbox column.  The second code block is for the click of a checkbox in the row.  Are either of those code blocks the correct event points to grab other cell data?  Is there a different event block that should be tracked to get the row data?  I don't even know what question to ask.  And that gets a checkdown?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are not using the datatables templates and server side loading and just applying it to a prebuilt table, you can add a unique identifier for the row in the markup for the checkbox, the "Billed" source, and "paid" destination so that you can (using a data attribute data-row-id=XXX):

1. associate the change event on all checkboxes in the table in document.ready
2. in the event handler for the change event, read the data-row-id value
3. locate the paid source var amount = $("span[data-row-id=XXX]).text()
4. assign to the paid input $("input[data-row-id=XXX]).val(amount);